# How to build customized reports for the entities detected in IBM Watson

Tags: entity, reporting

I am working on a conversation for a customer on the IBM Watson Bluemix space. There are two entities defined that have the same values as this is the requirement of the conversation.

User_Response: No
Exit_Chat_Unsucessful: No

Where User_Response captures both values "yes" and "no" and similar utterances while Exit_Chat_Unsuccessful tracks the count of conversations that did not end successfully.

Now since the value of both entities is set to "No", as part of the usual reporting the count for Exit_Chat_Unsuccessful would not be specific for exit chat alone.

How do I filter such values as part of reporting on Watson

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear what you are asking, but as I understand it you want to know when a branch has been exited due to an unsuccessful reason.

There is a couple of ways to do this.

1. You can specify a name for the exit node. Then use this in the logs to associate which entity is priority.
2. You can use "branch_exited" and "branch_exited_reason" to see if you left the branch correctly.

You can also redefine the "yes" and "no" values to a single entity. There should be no instance where you would need both. If there is, you can use contextual entities to train the system to understand which is which.